# How to have a Symfony API GET call return an embedded json object instead of an IRI

Tags: symfony, doctrine, php-7.1, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have been working on a Symfony API with Api Platform and have autogenerated all the endpoints which works fine. Except for one thing, when GETting a entity with a child entity, the child entity is not given in json but in an IRI format so this means that we get "/api/locations/1" instead of a JSON Object. I have been trying for hours but can't figure out how to change this. We are using annotations for the routes and the database relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some nice tool like [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/).
Then you can see the JSON response pretty printed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same, common normalization group for all embeded entities as desribed in [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#normalization).

The same is required for GraphQL when you need embeded fields other than id - asking for more than available results "Internal server error" "Cannot return null for non-nullable field XXX.YYY" - using GraphiQL helps with debugging more than POSTMAN (great tool) - when GraphQL will be working as expected, REST should be OK, too.

Unfortunatelly standard admin-on-rest doesn't like 'already fetched' values, expecting strings/IRIs only, not objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the response content type:

[image]